# Android Studio Canary 4.1 Memory settings

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Loading settings]
I'm trying to increase my heap size, but the android studio setting window keeps loading. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9? I had the same issue when migrating to Canary 9, and traced it through `idea.log` in `%APPDATA%\Local\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1\log\`, which for me reads

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 76: S:\Android\Android Studio\Canary\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions,C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1\studio64.exe.vmoptions
```

4.1 Canary 9 is the first release based off of IDEA 2020.1 and has [a new system for storing configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#directory-configuration-changes) (in the `%APPDATA%` folder rather than the hidden `.AndroidStudioX.X` folders of the past). It seems like a new `studio64.exe.vmoptions` (the file which holds memory settings) is being created in the configuration folder, in addition to its original location at the install location, so when the parser gets to the second path, it throws that error. I solved it by deleting both files and restarting Android Studio, which made the memory settings reappear for me.